# where to download faceMasculine.jpg faceFeminine.jpg textures?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

All the youtube tutorial folks seem to have a texture called: faceMasculine.jpg and faceFeminine.jpg

I can't seem to figure out where to download it? I don't see it on the Spark AR website, nor in an example project. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark, go to Help > Get Face Reference Assets:

[image]